# outer array of images in Django serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, orm

Im trying to call image url by `book`, this is my model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class PhotoBook(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="photos")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "cover_page", blank = True, null = True)
```

This is my `serializer.py`

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    users = UserSerializer(many = True, read_only = True)
    photos = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    published_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d", input_formats=None)
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("published_date" , "photos", "users", "isbn", "title_book",
                "cover_page", "pages" ,"copies", "description", "subtitle")
```

Sure im trying with `serializer.StringRelatedField`
 but only get an array of text saying this is an object of `Photobook`type.

The question is , how can  i get the array of images in my serializer, knowing the `foreing_key` is in the PhotoBook object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to achieve what you need:

````
class BookSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    photos = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("published_date" , "photos", "users", "isbn", "title_book",
                 "cover_page", "pages" ,"copies", "description", "subtitle")

    def get_photos(self, obj):
        # photos = obj.photos.all()
        # This work better for me, because Books objects doesn´t have 
        # the attribute photos, but PhotoBooks, contain the ```book_id```
        photos = PhotoBook.objects.filter(book=obj.id)
        return [photo.image.url for photo in photos]
````

Comment: Thanks  @neverwalkaloner, im edit the second line of function of get_photos , to this ```photos = PhotoBook.objects.filter(book=obj.id)```. c: